# Блендинг в opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Есть задача: наложить одно изображение (`png`) на другое (фон, считаем, что альфаканал все время равен 1 (диапазон 0:1)) и так, чтобы пиксели смешались в соответсвии с альфаканалом. Формула простая:

```
out = fon * (1 - alfa) + image * alfa
```

где:

```
fon - пиксель фона
image - пиксель налагаемого изображения
alfa - альфаканал налагаемого изображения
```

Реализовал подобный блендинг кастомно, через цикл, но, как я пологаю, в `opencv` уже есть функции, которые это реализуют более оптимально (еще и через `gpu`), но, к сожалению, все что нашел, это `addWeighted`, но параметр `alfa` (и `beta`) задаются при вызове этой функции, а не берутся из изображения. Как же это сделать через функции `opencv`?